# Ubuntu 12.04 - e1000e slow performance

Tags: 12.04, kernel, performance, intel, ethernet

I'm running Ubuntu 12.04 on a Thinkpad W510.

lspci reports this ethernet controller

```
00:19.0 Ethernet controller: Intel Corporation 82577LM Gigabit Network Connection (rev 06)
```

By default the e1000e kernel module is used for this ethernet connection and I'm seeing very poor network performance compared to Windows 7.

- Ubuntu 12.04 ~20 MBps
- Win7 100MBps

It is negotiating a proper 1gig full duplex connection but the performance still sucks.
Note I ended up downloading the latest driver from intels website which seemed to be a few versions ahead but it made no difference.

```
[12619.167149] e1000e 0000:00:19.0: PCI INT A disabled
[12625.523148] e1000e: Intel(R) PRO/1000 Network Driver - 2.0.0.1-NAPI
[12625.523154] e1000e: Copyright(c) 1999 - 2012 Intel Corporation.
[12625.523222] e1000e 0000:00:19.0: PCI INT A -> GSI 20 (level, low) -> IRQ 20
[12625.523250] e1000e 0000:00:19.0: setting latency timer to 64
[12625.534516] e1000e 0000:00:19.0: irq 54 for MSI/MSI-X
[12625.725027] e1000e 0000:00:19.0: eth0: (PCI Express:2.5GT/s:Width x1) f0:de:f1:48:2c:17
[12625.725037] e1000e 0000:00:19.0: eth0: Intel(R) PRO/1000 Network Connection
[12625.725299] e1000e 0000:00:19.0: eth0: MAC: 10, PHY: 10, PBA No: A002FF-0FF
[12625.856777] e1000e 0000:00:19.0: irq 54 for MSI/MSI-X
[12625.912457] e1000e 0000:00:19.0: irq 54 for MSI/MSI-X
[12628.803772] e1000e: eth0 NIC Link is Up 1000 Mbps Full Duplex, Flow Control: Rx
```

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, the e1000e will become biased against certain traffic styles. See,

http://support.dell.com/support/edocs/network/intelpro/r231521/en/e1000e.htm

Whatever you're using for a benchmark (netperf?), pay attention to the type
of loads that are causing you the most angst and troubleshoot from there.
I don't have a blanket solution for you but that Dell doc looks like a good
start.